# How to count same value in different variable in php:

Tags: variables, count

`$a=E;$b=D;$c=E;$d=A;`
So I want to count how many 'E' or 'D' or 'A'?
Is this possible to perform this coding?

Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_count_values` function

```
$a='E';
$b='D';
$c='E';
$d='A';

$values = array($a, $b, $c, $d);

$vals = array_count_values($values);
print_r($vals); // Array ( [E] => 2 [D] => 1 [A] => 1 )
```

Comment: Then how to store the vale of 'E' i.e. 2 in a new variable? Actually I want to find out number of 'E' and store the value in a new variable.

Comment: as you see the result of `array_count_values($values)` is an array, so you can make a loop with `foreach` and get the keys and values for each element.